# Mysql Collation does not work

Tags: mysql, insert, collation

I insert some text which i scrap from remote server and the problem is that in the text here is symbol.
 �  which makes a syntax error insert doe not work .Any ideas about this a 
paradox????? I've tried almost all collation nothing works.Text is in armenian.

```
   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '


            ՄԱԿ-ի գլխավոր քա�' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the statement (not just the error message).

Comment: It _probably_ means that the scrape did not grab an entire set of utf8 characters -- the black diamond (and perhaps more stuff) did not have complete utf8-encoded characters.

Comment: Armenian, in utf8, is hex `D4xx` or `D5xx`.  It is as if the paste ended with `D4` without the rest of the 'character'.

Comment: the statement works perfectly with a dummy text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED..!!!The problem was when create an instance of PDO I didn't mention this part
                 charset=utf8